# Azure Functions JavaScript Local Development Environment Variables

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

When developing Azure Functions in JavaScript [locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local), how would one get/set Node environment variables to use when running the functions locally with [azure-functions-core-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-functions-core-tools) `func host start --debug`?

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#environment-variables) for Azure Functions in JavaScript demonstrate targeting Function App application settings via `process.env[settingName]`. This seems to work great when published/deployed pulling the values from application settings of the azure function app.

When trying to log local node environment variables (Windows) within the function that were set using either `$env:FOO="bar"` (powershell) or `set FOO=bar` in the command prompt, it logs undefined. Attempting to log these values using command `context.log(process.env['FOO'])`.

**index.js**

```
const foo = process.env["FOO"];

module.exports = function (context, req) {
    context.log('bar') // successfully logs 'bar' in the azure function log
    context.log(foo); // logs undefined

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: "Hello " + (req.query.name || req.body.name)
        };
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
    context.done();
};
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using `local.settings.json` file in the root of your function app?

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FOO": "-- Your Value --",
  }
}
```

Comment: My local project is using a `local.settings.json`.  Would I access "FOO" in your example via `process.env["FOO"]`? Thanks!

Comment: I was able to successfully access the values using process.env[settingName] by adding to the `Values` property of `local.settings.json`. You rock, thanks!

Comment: Correct, the `local.settings.json` file is a way to locally emulate the Application Settings once you deploy.